# How can I prevent Android Activity from briefly entering portrait mode when I have specified landscape?

Tags: android

I have specified my Activity should be fixed to landscape, which works most of the time.  ***Specifically, when the Activity is already running, and I launch a new instance of it from Eclipse***, the Activity starts in Portrait and immediately changes to Landscape--but not before the View has already been told it was Portrait.  ***So my View is initialized as Portrait, but gets a surfaceChanged immediately.***

I have the following specified in my manifest:

```
    <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

I have also tried:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

When I was targeting API level 7, I believe this worked fine.  Now I target API level8, and a strange quirk has appeared.

In the oncreate method, the value of:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

is:

```
Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
```

Immediately after creating the Activity, the orientation is changed to Landscape, I receive a `surfacechanged`, and I can "fix" everything.  But why is it ever portrait?

I suspect it has to do with the fact that the application is autorotated as it launches from a portrait screen.  It seems bizarre that the application, which has been instructed to NEVER be in portrait, starts that way, and then quickly changes.

But, is there a way to not allow it to ever be in portrait?

I put this in my Activity's `onCreate`:

```
while (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
{
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

This resulted in it getting stuck there forever :)

Comment: did you tried specifying orientation as landscape by setting the property orientation = "landscape" in ur activity tag in manifest file..?

Comment: Yes.  That is the first thing I stated in my question.

Comment: I've got same problem with libGDX game

Comment: Seeing the same problem here, but haven't found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity :

```
@Override 
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);     
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
}
```

Comment: This does not work.  It has an interesting side effect, though.  Now, the view starts in Portrait, and on the first SurfaceChanged, is still in portrait.  By the second SurfaceChanged, it is in landscape.  Previously, the surface only changed once.  It doesn't make sense that this would work, anyway, because what I want is for the configuration to never change, but always be Landscape...

Answer (score -1):

Define orientation in your menifest.

screenOrientation ="landscape"

OR

set the setRequestOrientation(...) before the setContentView(...) in your activity.

Comment: on what device & osversion you are testing ?

Comment: check your device setting, it is might be locked for auto rotation.

Comment: I have tested on Droid, Droid 2, and a 4.1 AVD.

Comment: set the setRequestOrientation(...) before the setContentView(...) in your activity.